# Increment localStorage value by one

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an attempted log in feature to our application. They fail three times it kicks them out altogether. To keep count of how many times they attempt I thought I would use localStorage because I can easily manipulate it. However, I am having trouble incrementing the value when they fail to authenticate themselves.

At the top, I am setting the localStorage variable

```
localStorage.setItem("attempts", "0")
```

and then if the server returns an error, I am trying to increment that value.

```
if(errorCode === 4936){
  var attempts = localStorage.getItem("attempts");
  localStorage.setItem(attempts++);
  console.log(attempts);
}
```

and obviously this is not working, but all I can find when I research is setting and getting the localStorage nothing about updating or changing. Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And in some cases you have to add **++** before **attempts**:

```
if (errorCode == 4936) {
  var attempts = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
  localStorage.setItem("attempts", ++attempts);
  console.log(attempts);
}
```

Comment: I'm receaving the error Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation  when I put this in.

Comment: Edited. You can't `++` something that isn't a variable. I overlooked it

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) `setItem` only accept DomString (UTF-16 String). So the answer should be

```
if (errorCode === 4936) {
 var attempts = (parseInt(localStorage.getItem('attempts'))+1);
 localStorage.setItem("attempts", attempts.toString());
 console.log(attempts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 issues here

1. You need to convert the number of attempts to a number before incrementing
2. In your second set statement you aren't specifying a key again
3. You are assigning the error code, not checking if it equals 4936

```
localStorage.setItem("attempts", "0");

if(errorCode == 4936){ // double equal is need to compare. Single equals is an assignment operator 
  var attempts = Number(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
  localStorage.setItem("attempts", ++attempts);
  console.log(attempts);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it yells at me when I take the quotes away from the 0 I think because localStorage will only take strings. This seems to work once, but when it comes back through the function it's just staying at "1"

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just tried it out and the number gets converted to a string automatically when stored. Updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: oh, I really have a greater sign in there It must have gotten deleted when I copy and pasted. It still seems that I can't increment then number more than the first time it runs through. Once it hits one it stays at one.

Comment: Are you certain the section `localStorage.setItem("attempts", "0");` does not get run more than once?

Comment: I have also changed `attempts++` to `++attempts`

Answer (score 1):

You should be use like this.It's works for me.

```js
if(errorCode === 4936){
  var attempts = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
  localStorage.setItem("attempts",`${++attempts}`);
  console.log(attempts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is not really correct, because if the item `attempts` doesn't exists in localStorage:

```
localStorage.getItem('attempts') // null
parseInt(null) // NaN
```

Correct way in typescript will be

```
 const currentAttempts = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('attempts') ?? '0')
 localStorage.setItem('attempts', (currentAttempts + 1).toString())
```