# How to increment a number in local storage on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I read the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046762/1018804). Basically I have a `button` and when i click it, it increases the `number` in my `localStorage` and set it as a text in a `span`:

**When the page first loads:**

```
$("#jikubox span").text(localStorage.length);
```

**Click function:**

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
  var curId = $(".my_post_id").data("id");
  $("#input_post_id").val(curId);
  localStorage.setItem("attempts", "0");
  var attempts = Number(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
  localStorage.setItem("attempts", ++attempts);
  $("#jikubox span").text(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
});
```

But if I do the following I always get `1`

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
```

Comment: Well, you're setting `attempts` to 0 then increment it in your click handler ...

Comment: Because every time you click on button you are setting it to 0(zero) first on this line. `localStorage.setItem("attempts", "0");`. Then by increasing it you always set it to 1.

Comment: @Zenoo ouch! True!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are always resetting the localStorage value to 0 in this line:

`localStorage.setItem("attempts", "0");`

Try this instead, check to see if the localStorage property is unset, and only add the default of 0 if it's unset:

`if (!localStorage.attempts) localStorage.attempts = '0';`

Comment: whoops, thanks a lot. WIll accept this as you've been the first

Comment: hey one last thing, I need to stop the click from adding if the local storage is equal 2, i tried       `if(localStorage.getItem("attempts") >= 2) {
        alert("nope");
        localStorage.attempts = '2'
      }` but I get the alert as it becomes 2

Comment: That's the right method, you probably aren't adding the code in the right place - put it at the very top of the handler.

Comment: like this?     `$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
      if(localStorage.getItem("attempts") >= 2) {
        alert("nope");
        localStorage.attempts = '2'
      }
      if(localStorage.getItem("attempts") < 2) {
        var curId = $(".my_post_id").data("id");
        $("#input_post_id").val(curId);
        if (!localStorage.attempts) localStorage.attempts = '0';
        var attempts = Number(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
        localStorage.setItem("attempts", ++attempts);
        $("#jikubox span").text(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
      }
    });`

Comment: The code would look nicer if you simply returned early on the bad condition, rather than creating another block for the main logic: `if (localStorage.getItem("attempts") >= 2) { alert('nope'); return; }` Then you don't need another `if` block below

Comment: so basically     `$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
      if (!localStorage.attempts) localStorage.attempts = '0';
      if (localStorage.getItem("attempts") >= 2) { alert('nope'); return; }
      var curId = $(".my_post_id").data("id");
      $("#input_post_id").val(curId);
    });`

Comment: actually that's not adding any value when I click